# Disable NSWindow snapping / stickiness programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

In recent versions of macOS, `NSWindow`'s default behavior is to become sticky when being resized/re positioned near to another window (even in a different application).

Does anyone know of a way to disable this for a specific window in my app? Or at least stop my window from sticking to other windows - it should be okay if other apps want to stick beside my window.

Cheers, and happy new year!